# How to setup Xdebug in docker, and setup configuration in PhpStorm

Tags: docker, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I have set up Xdebug in docker, step debugging is enabled but I want to start developer helper and Tracing in Xdebug. Can you please help me how to set up the configuration in PhpStorm after setting up Xdebug.

[image: from phpinfo]

[image: configuration in PhpStorm]

Comment: *"but I want to start developer helper and Tracing in Xdebu"* Check https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode -- `xdebug.mode=debug,develop,trace`

Comment: *"Can you please help me how to set up the configuration in PhpStorm after setting up Xdebug."* 1) https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/08/quickstart-with-docker-in-phpstorm/ 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ 3)